# Are there computational complexity results for generative adversarial networks?

Tags: time-complexity, p-vs-np, game-theory

First time posting on here; if this question is too rough I would appreciate if you could point me to a stackexchange forum where this question may be a better fit.

Generative adversarial networks (GANs), [introduced here](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2014/hash/5ca3e9b122f61f8f06494c97b1afccf3-Abstract.html) by Ian Goodfellow, are a setup to train a neural generator $G_\phi$ which is supposed to learn to generate new samples from a distribution (of e.g. images) and a discriminator $D_\theta$ which judges whether the samples proposed by the generator are fake or belong to the true distribution. When I intuitively apply the $P  vs. NP$ question of whether  "every problem whose solutions can be quickly verified can also be checked quickly" to this setup, I end up asking whether, if one showed that the task of learning the function $D_\theta$ learns is polynomial in time, this would imply something about the time complexity of the generator.

Is it wrong to think of the generator as the problem solver in this context, and to think of the discriminator as the checker of the solution? I recognise the way I phrase the question is far too rough to give a meaningful or definitive answer, but am asking for pointers to think about this correctly since I struggle to apply the computational complexity perspective to this specific setup.

I am mostly interested in references to papers or other resources that make computational complexity statements about GANs or other generative models, or the task of neural function approximation in general.

PS. I do recognise that one can make computational complexity statements about both generator and discriminator just by looking at the models and training algorithm, but have the intuition that there should be more abstract inferences to be made about the difficulty of generating, given one knows how difficult the task of discriminating is.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by "learn $D_\theta$ in polynomial time"?  Exactly what counts as learning it?  I ask because it doesn't seem as trivial to specify as you might think, because whether $D_\theta$ is successful depends on $G_\phi$.